# How to calculate a new date from a date field in an array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, date

[what my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mus0l.png)

I am trying to calculate the ship date from the order_date, supposed to be 4 days from order_date. How can I access the element in the array and perform the arithmetic?

Comment: include image not link

Comment: What elements do you have right now. I mean, are you asking generally how to connect to the DB and fetch data?

Comment: @Minsky—no, not an image, text.

Comment: Would be great if you can share some sample data and the expected output. [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) will be a nice tool.